# How to make Safari 15 toolbar always black

Tags: macos, safari, big-sur

The Safari 15 toolbar changes color based on... something. I think maybe the favicon of the current webpage?

I would prefer it to always be black. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari > Preferences… > Tabs > uncheck "Show colour in tab bar"

Comment: Thanks. Now if only there were a "Tab Layout: None." option